# What is the probability of collecting all 50 state quarters from a bucket of 1000 of them based on known probabilities of each zone of origin?

Tags: probability, coupon-collector

I live in the Eastern time zone of USA.  Assume that there are 5 "zones" the USA is divided into for this problem (Eastern, Central, Mountain, Pacific, and Alaska + Hawaii).  Also assume that if the probability of finding a distinct (needed) quarter in my own (Eastern) zone is p (for the first one drawn from the bucket of 1000), then the other zones would be p/2, p/3, p/4, and p/30 respectively (also on the first draw from the bucket of 1000).  For example, the probability of me finding a needed quarter in my own time zone (Eastern) is 4 times as great as me finding one from one from the Pacific zone.  Another way of looking at it is it is 4 times as difficult for me to find a needed quarter from CA than it is from Florida (FL) for example.  Also note that "bad" quarters (not needed) will NOT go back into the main bucket, but rather into a 2nd bucket of "repeats" which we will never draw from.  For simplicity, assume there are 12 states in each of the 4 main zones except for the 5th zone which is only Alaska and Hawaii.  I separated those 2 states since they are non-continental, thus I assigned them a higher difficulty than any of the other 48 states.

So assuming I have a bucket of 1000 normally circulated state quarters (none of the old style "non-state" quarters), what is the probability I will get all 50 states "covered" in that bucket of 1000 quarters?  That is, at least one of each state quarter.

As a bonus question, what is the probability I can fill 2 coin albums with all 50 state quarters from that same bucket of 1000 (100 "good" quarters needed total).

Reason I ask is I will actually be doing this and was curious how to compute this probability mathematically.

Comment: The correct search term here is "*Non-uniform* [coupon collector's problem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Coupon_collector%27s_problem)"

Comment: You haven't said anything about the probabilities of drawing quarters from particular states. Are you assuming that the probability is the same for all states in the same time zone? If so, is that at all realistic?

Comment: Yes assume the probability of any state in the same zone is the same as that of any other state in that same zone.  No it is not realistic but it is to simplify the problem.

Comment: So, to make sure we get this right: The probability of the entire Pacific zone is $p/5$, so both Alaska and Hawaii have a probability of $(p/5)/2=p/10$, whereas e.g. California only has probability $(p/4)/12=p/48$? Or are $p/4$ and $p/5$ already the probabilities per state in those zones? (I think you should edit the question to clarify it in this regard; e.g. you write that "the probability of me finding a needed quarter in my own time zone (Eastern) is 4 times as great as me finding one from say California (CA) (in the Pacific zone)", so there you seem to be comparing a zone with a state.)

Comment: Another question: Why the second bucket and the information that you won't draw from that? Since your question is whether the entire bucket contains one quarter (or two) from each state, the concept of drawing from it seems irrelevant?

Comment: The p, p/2, p/3, p/4 and p/5 are the relative probabilites of each of the 5 zones.  You can assume than ANY of the 12 states in a particular zone are equally likely (such as CA and AZ being equally likely).  Drawing is conceptually being done because imagine I had 1 or 2 coin books/albums and draw 1 quarter at a time, either putting it in album A or album B or putting it in the "repeat" bucket.

Comment: @joriki:  I would think the desired approach is that all states in the East each  have an equal probability, which is $5$ times higher than either Alaska or Hawaii.

Comment: @David: Are you aware that if $p$ through $p/5$ are the probabilities (I'm not sure what you mean by "relative probabilities") of the **zones**, then Hawaii will have probability $p/10$ and California will have probability $p/48$? I agree with Ross that it seems more likely that what you actually want is that Hawaii has $p/5$ and California has $p/4$, i.e., that $p$ through $p/5$ are the probabilities of the **states**.

Comment: @RossMillikan: That's already in the question: For simplicity, $12$ per zone except $2$ in Pacific.

Comment: For clarity, assume that the relative difficultly of getting coins in the 5 zones are 1x, 2x, 3x, 4x, 5x where 1x is the difficulty of getting ANY state in my same Eastern zone.  So for example, FL and PA are equally likely quarters. To get a AK or HI quarter would be 5x (5 times as difficult).  Don't worry about different states in the same zone, they are considered equally likely as any other state in that same zone.  In reality that would not be true but assume so here for this problem to make it simpler, and no not 2 in Pacific, Pacific has 12.  AK and HI are a new 5th zone I made up.

Comment: Sorry, yes, $5$th zone, not Pacific. @David, I think you keep misstating what it is you actually want. Everything in your last comment confirms Ross' interpretation of the question, except the first sentence, where you say again that " the relative difficulty of getting coins in the 5 *zones* are ...", where it seems that what you mean is the relative difficulty/probability of getting coins in particular *states* of those zones. The probability of getting a coin in zone $5$ is not $p/5$ but $2p/5$, and the probability of getting a coin in zone $4$ is not $p/4$ but $12p/4$.

Comment: Ok, I guess I messed that part up in the way I worded it.  What I mean is if there were 12 states also in zone 5, then the probability of getting one from that zone would be 5 times as difficult as getting one from zone 1 (Eastern), so since there are only 2 states in zone 5 (instead of 12), the actual difficulty is 6*5 = 30x as difficult as getting a coin from ANY Eastern state in zone 1.  Sorry for the confusion.  My answer to my own question shows this 30:1 difference in difficulty.

Comment: I wonder if it's true that the probability of getting a quarter for a nearby state is higher than that of getting a quarter for a distant state. I would have guessed that the quarters are evenly distributed geographically, in which case your assumption about zones is a complicating assumption, not a simplifying assumption. (Consider the fact that all state quarters are *from* Pennsylvania, Colorado or California.)

Comment: Maybe true, but that would be 3 zones instead of 5 so not much difference.  This is just a fun mental, mathematical, and computer simulation exercise anyway.  The "real" (estimated) probabilities could be changed by a person wanting to know that information. For me, I was just curious about the 5 zones, even though they may not be representative of how the quarters are really distributed.  To make it even more realistic, you wold also have to consider non state quarters mixed in, a few Canadian quarters, some that are damaged (possibly indeterminate)...  My problem has been simplified greatly.

Answer (score 1):

You can compute the chance of each state by choosing $p$ so the probabilities add to $1$.  Let the probabilities of each state be $q_i$ where $i$ runs from $1$ to $50$ and the states are in some order.  We can make a slight approximation by assuming whether you get each state is independent.  This is not quite true, because if you have at least two New York quarters you have slightly less chance to have two Vermont quarters, but it will not be far off.  The chance you do not get state $i$ is 
$\left(1-q_i\right)^{1000}$ so the chance you do get state $i$ is $1-\left(1-q_i\right)^{1000}$.  The chance you have all $50$ states is then 
$$\prod_{i=1}^{50}1-\left(1-q_i\right)^{1000}$$
The chance you get exactly one quarter of state $i$ is $1000q_i\left(1-q_i\right)^{999}$ from the binomial distribution, so the chance you have at least two of state $i$ is $1-\left(1-q_i\right)^{1000}-1000q_i\left(1-q_i\right)^{999}$.  The chance you have at least two of each state is then $$\prod_{i=1}^{50}1-\left(1-q_i\right)^{1000}-1000q_i\left(1-q_i\right)^{999}$$

With $12$ states in each of the first four time zones, we solve $12p(1+\frac 12+\frac 13+\frac 14)+\frac {2p}5=1$ and have $p=\frac 5{127}$, so $q_i=\frac5{127}$ for $12$ states, $\frac 5{254}$ for $12$ more, and $\frac 1{127}$ for Alaska and Hawaii.  I make it about $0.99863$ chance of having at least one of each state and $0.98653$ chance of having at least two of each state.  Here the expected number of Alaska and Hawaii quarters is almost $8$ each, so you really expect to have two of each.

Answer (score 0):

I will simulate this on a computer to check the mathematical results. To generate a "weighted random" bucket of 1000 quarters, I will use the ratios of $72,000 : 36,000 : 24,000 : 18,000 : 2,400$ for the 5 zones respectively.  Note that those are all divisible by 12 and it allows for all 1000 quarters to be from any single state, just as it could be in real life, although extremely unlikely.  So the correct expected values will be retained. I will just put these in an array and choose 1000 unique random numbers from 1..152,400 inclusive, and then add each of those quarters to the bucket, then see if I can fill all 50 states from them (perhaps even retaining the average # of quarters used to make this happen).  I will do thousands of simulations to get a good average and will report back the results maybe in a few days.